# Custom icon CSS not working as expected

Tags: css, font-awesome

I've got Font Awesome on a site running wordpress and I want to change the icons to use custom icons.

I've tried things like addressing it in CSS and changing it but with no luck. Any ideas are very welcomed right now.

```
i.fa.fa-pencil {
    content: url(http://mskmartialarts.co.uk/wp- 
    content/uploads/2015/07/karate.jpg);
    background-image: url("http://mskmartialarts.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/karate.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the CSS that Font Awesome employs for that icon: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/css/font-awesome.css#L358

It's actually the `:before` pseudo-element where they're setting the glyph:

```
.fa-pencil:before {
  content: "\f040";
}
```

So you'll need to do the same in your code:

```
i.fa.fa-pencil:before {
  content: url('http://mskmartialarts.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/karate.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why work against Font-Awesome? Instead create your own icon classes in css.

```
.custom-icon {
    background: url("http://mskmartialarts.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/karate.jpg") center no-repeat;
  background-size:100%;
  padding:10px;
}
<i class="custom-icon">&nbsp;</i> Blah
```

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNjLea)

Comment: This won't prevent Font Awesome from continuing to append the original icon via the `:before` pseudo-element. You'd need to add something like `.fa-pencil:before{ content: ''; }` to what you've suggested.

Comment: Right. My answer was instead of over-writing font-awesome, simply create your own icon class. I updated my answer to curb the confusion.